# How to retrieve the latest object added (new one) in Django models and display it in the template?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-filter

l got a problem. Am trying to retrieve a single latest object added everytime, and display it in the template.
Below is my codes but;

Help me figure it out the source of the problem in these different instances below

**Problem Number 1**

```
#Action/models.py

class ActionGame(models.Model):
        name=models.Charfield()
        published=models.DateTimeField()
```

```
#Action/views.py
 from Action.models import ActionGame

 def action (request):
        latest_action=ActionGame.objects.filter(published=published). latest()
        Context={ 'latest_action': latest_action }
        return....
```

But it returns *error* :
**name 'published' is not defined**

**Problem Number 2**

```
#Action/models.py

 class ActionGame(models.Model):
     name=models.Charfield()
     published=models.DateTimeField()
     class Meta:
       get_latest_by='published'
```

```
#Action/views.py
........
latest_action=ActionGame.objects. latest()
.......
```

#but it returns *error* :
**'ActionGame' object is not iterable**

Even if I try this:

```
............
latest_action=ActionGame.objects. latest('published')
.......
```

#it returns the *Same error*:
**'ActionGame' object is not iterable**

But this second issue, the *error is referred in #action.html*

```
{% for x in latest _action %}
<p>{{ x.game_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Please l need your assistance.
Thanks

Comment: u import actions model?

Comment: yes i did `from Action.models import ActionGame`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve those things only using `.latest()` query method like this.

#### models.py

```py
class DebitDemo(models.Model):
    amt = models.IntegerField(default=0)  
    created_at = models.DateField()
```

#### views.py

```py
def DemoView(request):
  get_data = DebitDemo.objects.latest('id')
  context = {'get_data':get_data}
  return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

#### HTML code

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Salary</th>
            <th scope="col">Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{get_data.amt}}</td>
            <td>{{get_data.created_at}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  l hope it works , but someone referred me to Meta Class , `ordering=['published']`